# Making the Swedish characters å, ä and ö appear

Tags: characters, input-encodings

I need to use the following preamble but can not make the Swedish letters å, ä and ö appear. The part in Swedish is in the separate file called intro_summary.tex. I'm using TeXShop as my editor. I think it has something to do with the line "\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}" because without it I can compile the document but the symbols do not appear correctly.

When I have written in Swedish in the past I had to include "\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}" to make it work but this time, when I need to use this specific template, it does not help me.

Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{UUThesisTemplate}

% Package to determine wether XeTeX is used
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
% XeTeX specific packages and settings
% Language, diacritics and hyphenation
\usepackage[babelshorthands]{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{swedish}
%\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} %additional

% Font settings
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\else
% Plain LaTeX specific packages and settings
% Language, diacritics and hyphenation
    % Use English and Swedish languages. 

\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
% Font settings
\usepackage{type1cm}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amscd,dsfont,psfrag,color}

% Enable scaling of images on import

\fi 
\begin{document}
\input{intro_summary.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: are you using xelatex?  that operates entirely in unicode (utf-8 encoded); it won't cope with `applemac` encoding or even standard encodings like `latin 1`.

Comment: Try replacing `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. At any rate, the input encoding of your tex file should be independent of whether you compile it with pdflatex or xelatex, right?

Comment: What editor are you using?  And how are you planning to compile this document? Paste this into a new document, and then with your editor, when you save choose "UTF-8" as the encoding for the file. Then change `latin1` to `utf8` in the source.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I am using TeXShop (and no xelatex as far as I know). When I save as utf-8 and replace the latin1 with utf8 I can no longer compile and get the following message:   "Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is und
efined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'."

Comment: Please remove the `\input{intro_summary.tex}` from your example document (which we can not process) and replace by the minimal amount of text that demonstrates the error,

Comment: @David Carlisle: That file doesn't contain anything special so that line can just be replaced by åäö. I'm beginning to find out what is wrong. When I deleted a lot of definitions of the form \renewcommand{\a }{\alpha } etc. it suddenly worked! I'm not sure exactly what is making it not work...

Comment: `\renewcommand{\a }{\alpha } ` that would be a _really_ bad idea. The reason why `\newcommand` warns if you are redefining things is to warn you might break something, `\renewcommand` says that's OK I know what I'm doing and it's OK to redefine latex insides.....   `\a` is a latex command used to define accented letters.....

Comment: @user48102 also, deleted from  _where_ ? if the problem is in code that you haven't shown it is not surprising that no answer has been posted.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I see, thank you for your answer. I took away the part of the preamble I thought had nothing to do with the problem. Else it would have been several pages. I removed all extraneous code that I did not use anyway and then it worked (and it was not the \alpha ). Not sure exactly what it was but I'm happy it works now. Thank you all for your suggestions!